# Highlighting non traditional duplicates in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a macro which can solve this problem? I am trying to identify the entries in a spreadsheet which are presented like this chicken-horse and horse-chicken. In my case these are duplicates and I need to get rid of one. Is this possible? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [***Have you tried anything?***](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Are the individual parts of the entries always separated by hyphens? If so, split into parts at the hyphen, sort parts into alphabetical order, rejoin the parts then compare

Comment: @barrowc good point, if they are ALWAYS sperated by -, then you just need to parse out each line as your comparing, if there is no rhyme or reason, still do able but much harder.

Comment: Yes, this problem could be solved by a macro.  You can apply @barrowc solution in a macro; perhaps including other possible separators.  Give it a try and show us your code if you run into a problem; or present it as the answer if you do not.

Comment: Thanks guys for the great suggestions! BarrowC and holmesIV, we are definitely on the same page as that is what I has originally intended to do. John Coleman, I will definitely try your process!  I was just curious as to whether there was a way to automate the process macro-wise.

Answer (score 0):

VBA isn't needed (unless you want to automate the process for repeated invocation). You could do the following steps (expanding on barrowc's suggestion, which can also be used in VBA)

For simplicity, I will assume the data is in Column A, starting in row 1. Adjust accordingly if it is somewhere else. Insert a couple of working columns to the right of A if B and C currently contain data.

Step 1) Use text-to-columns (on the data tab) with "-" as the delimiter

Step 2) In C1 enter the formula

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(A1<B1,A1,B1),"-",IF(A1<B1,B1,A1))
```

and copy it down the column

Step 3) use the remove-duplicates (again on the data tab) with column C the column to be searched for duplicates

Step 4) Delete columns A,B if you want -- they've served their purpose.

A pure VBA approach would probably use split() rather than text-to-columns, but if you are just learning VBA you could always follow the above steps with the macro recorder turned on and try to tweak the resulting code.

Comment: Thanks guys for the great suggestions! BarrowC and holmesIV, we are definitely on the same page as that is what I has originally intended to do. John Coleman, I will definitely try your process!  I was just curious as to whether there was a way to automate the process macro-wise.